# Заставка на Canvas

Tags: c#, wpf, zoom, shape, wpf-canvas

Подскажите пожалуйста реально ли сделать что-то типа заставки на Canvas? Но сложность вся заключается в том что заставка должна будет передвигаться, увеличиваться, уменьшаться и она должна быть что-то вроде без ограничений(бесконечно можно передвигать). Вот такая сложная задачка (
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: _"заставка должна будет передвигаться, увеличиваться, уменьшаться"_ -- сама по себе или в ответ на события мыши?

Comment: @Stack в ответ на событие мыши. Ну то есть колёсиком происходит приближение, отдаление, а зажатие колёсика на мышке и перетаскивание её, это передвижение

Comment: _"в ответ на событие мыши. Ну то есть колёсиком происходит приближение, отдаление"_ -- см. [Pan & Zoom Image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/741956/pan-zoom-image)

Comment: @Stack ну это понятно, а там будут создаваться автоматически исходные изображения, для того чтобы текстура была что-то типа бесконечной при перемещении?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если ваша текстура бесшовная, то можно уложить её "плиткой", тогда вы получите эффект бесконечности этой текстуры, так как она будет дорисовываться по мере необходимости.

Сделать это можно так(например для изображения 32 на 32 пикселя):

```
<ImageBrush ImageSource="Image.jpg" 
            Viewport="0,0,32,32"
            ViewportUnits="Absolute" 
            TileMode="Tile"/>
```

Это послужит бекграундом, а что это за звездочка нарисована у вас я так и не понял) Если это фигура которая должна уменьшатся и увеличиваться при помощи мыши, то нарисовать её можно при помощи `<Path/>`.

Comment: Ну это я так чиста для примера звёздочку поставил 